# Disable autosize in Pane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, pane

In Java docs says: (About Pane (JavaFX))

> Pane resizes each managed child regardless of the child's visible
>   property value;

How to disable this resize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `setManaged(false)` on the nodes you do not want to be managed by the pane.

If you want nodes not to take up space when you set visible to false, you can bind the managed property to the visible property:

```
myNode.managedProperty().bind(myNode.visibleProperty());
```